# Meaning of Minoccur and Nillable=true in WSDL?

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl

I want to insert an empty TAG in my XML request, what parameters should i set in WSDL for that particular element. For eg- MinOccur, Nillable etc.

Can we control this thing on Code level also? Using JAVA to set values in the element.

Answer (score 0):

How many times **must** the element occur at a minimum (`MinOccur`), and can it have a blank, `null` or `nil` in XML (`Nillable`).

Comment: If we do not set any value in that element, then would it add an empty TAG of that element?

Comment: @HimanshuTehri The server will reject any request that doesn't contain at least `MinOccur` instances of the TAG. If `Nillable=false` then it will reject any requests where the TAG is empty.

Comment: Thanks Elliott.. It is helpful. So what i am gonna achieve here is:- We are consumer of a WSDL. There is one element which could have some value or empty. But provider must want that element in the request either it has some value or empty.           So can they achieve this by setting MinOccurs=1 and nillable=true for that element in their WSDL?